# Renomear colunas nuḿericas no Pandas

Tags: pandas

Importei um arquivo Excel em um dataframe f0719. Só que o Pandas adicionou números, que não existiam no arquivo original, como identificação das colunas, ao invés do nome, que ficou logo abaixo, na segunda linha. Tentei renomear, via comando abaixo, que não dá nenhum erro, porém, as colunas não são renomeadas e permanecem com os números. Na figura 1 eu tenho o dataframe na forma como ele se encontra atualmente. E, na figura 2, como eu quero que ele fique.

```
f0719 = f0719.rename(columns={'0': 'Sigla da UPAG', '1': 'Identificação Única', '2': 'Nome', '3': 'CPF', '4':   'Cargo', '5':   'Especialidade', '6':   'Natureza do Cargo', '7':   'Carreira', '8':    'Sigla e Nível da Função de Confiança / Cargo em Comissão', '9': 'Atribuição do cargo comissionado / função de confiança', '10':    'Data de Nascimento', '11': 'Data de Exercício no Cargo Atual', '12':   'Data de Ingresso no Serviço Público', '13':    'Data de Ingresso na Carreira', '14':   'Data de Aposentadoria', '15':  'Data de Óbito', '16':  'Data de Exclusão', '17':   'Tempo de Contribuição', '18':  'Situação Funcional', '19': 'Categoria da Situação', '20':  'Origem', '21': 'Jornada', '22': 'Mês da folha/Ano', '23':  'Tipo de Competência', '24':    'Sequência da Folha', '25': 'Código Rubrica', '26': 'Descrição da Rubrica', '27':   'Código Rendimento Desconto', '28': 'Tipo da rubrica', '29':    'Valor', '30':  'Fundamento constitucional e legal da aposentadoria', '31': 'Proporção da aposentadoria'})
```

Como está o dataframe - colunas numéricas
[image: Figura 1 - Como o DF está]
O resultado que desejo obter - colunas com nomes
[image: Figura 2 - Como quero que fique]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode especificar a linha do excel que será o nome das colunas do dataframe do seguinte modo:

```
 pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', index_col=0)
```

mais informações sobre em : [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

apenas modificando, para seu caso seria:

```
colunas= f0719.iloc[0]
new_f0719  = pd.DataFrame(f0719.values[1:], columns=colunas)
```

e sem criar um novo dataframe:

```
f0719.rename(columns=f0719.iloc[0])
f0719.drop(f0719.index[0])
```

Comment: Mas uma vez que eu já importei, não há outra forma de apenas modificar?

Comment: Nâo deu certo o segundo comando, mas o primeiro funcionou. Obrigado.

Answer (score -2):

No caso em `pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', index_col=0)` o `index_col=0` está fazendo a coluna 0 como indíce do dataframe, e não a linha 0 como o nome das colunas do dataframe como você disse.

Comment: Legal você querer ajudar, mas você usou o campo de resposta para fazer um comentário. Você poderá postar comentários quando tiver [um pouco mais de pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor utilize o campo de resposta somente para postar uma solução ao problema de que a pergunta trata.